# Align :before with text both with same height

Tags: html, css

I've created a link which has a `:before` with an icon inside it.

I want the height of the text to be `30px` and the `:before` to also be 30px.

I'm finding that my text is sitting much lower and has a height of `40px` despite having no padding.

How can I make these two line up?

```
footer .social a:before {
    content:'';
    background-image:url(http://www.vpshosting.com/wp-content/themes/LondonLive/images/icon-twitter.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-right:10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
footer .social a.twitter:before {
    background-position:0px 0px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dv83ncwb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make `<a>` element display inline-block.

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height:30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I made fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dv83ncwb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Used to this css

**Define** your `.twitter` class this **css** and `footer .social a:before` define `vertical-align:top;`

```
.twitter{font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 30px;}
footer .social a:before {
    vertical-align: top;}
```

**Demo**

```css
.twitter{font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 30px;}
footer .social a:before {
    vertical-align: top;
    content:'';
    background-image:url(http://www.vpshosting.com/wp-content/themes/LondonLive/images/icon-twitter.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-right:10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
footer .social a.twitter:before {
    background-position:0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="social"> <a class="twitter">Twitter</a>

    </div>
</footer>
```